# POST ".wav" File to URL with Python, print Response How To?

Tags: python, file, post, python-requests

So here we have a Python script:

```
""" Record a few seconds of audio and save to a WAVE file. """

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                channels = CHANNELS,
                rate = RATE,
                input = True,
                frames_per_buffer = chunk)

print "* recording"
all = []
for i in range(0, RATE / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    all.append(data)
print "* done recording"

stream.close()
p.terminate()

# write data to WAVE file
data = ''.join(all)
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(data)
wf.close()
```

And this script does what the first comentary line says, if you run it in terminal it will output a ".wav" file in the path you're set in the moment of the execution... What I want to do is to get that file and "manipule" it, instead of outputting it to the Computer, I want to store it in a variable or something like that, and then I would like to POST it to an URL parsing some parametters along with it... I saw some interesting examples of posting **multipart-encoded files** using **requests**, as you can see here:

> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

But I made several attempts of achieving what I'm descripting in this question and I was unlucky... Maybe a little guidance will help with this one :)

Being Brief, what I need is to record a WAV file from microphone and then POST it to an URL (Parsing Data like the Headers with it) and then get the output in a print statement or something like that in the terminal...

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wave.open` lets you pass either a file name or a file-like object to save into. If you pass in a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object rather than `WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME`, you'll can get a string object that you can presumably use to construct a POST request.

Note that this will load the file into memory -- if it might be really long, you might prefer to do it [into a temporary file](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) and then use that to make your request. Of course, you're already loading it into memory, so maybe that's not an issue.

Comment: In Python 3, you also probably want [BytesIO](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead.

Comment: Ok, with this advice I'm getting an "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'" Error when launching the script, it actually records the audio, parses it into a variable (and if you try to print it, it is actually binary data) and then, when trying to POST the data, I get this error. ¿Why? *Using StringIO

Comment: Sounds like you're passing a string where something wants a dictionary (which has a `.items()` method). What's the line of code this happens on?

Comment: Here is the Complete new script: http://pastebin.com/MssgByJR I assume the error is located in the "actual posting" on line 48... If I set "filesend" to "filesend = audiofile" then I get: "StringIO instance has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: Oh! and here is the "log" of the error: http://pastebin.com/xXF9d65q if it helps.

Comment: If you look at [the `requests.post` documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), `files` is supposed to be a dictionary with file names as keys and filelike objects as values. so what we actually want is to first do `audiofile.seek(0)` so it'll read from the start, then pass `files={'clip.wav', audiofile}`. Give that a try...

Comment: Also note that in Puthon 2 you should really be doing `try: import cStringIo as StringIo; except ImportError: import StringIo`. That'll load the faster version written in C if it's available, otherwise the slower version written in Python.

Comment: I made it! Ended up using a temporary file because the StringIO "object" didn't work at all for what I was trying to do... Also I LOVED requests BUT it didn't worked for this either... Had to use urlib2... Anyway, Thanks for your advices!!! Finally achieved what I wanted ;)